# register domain name in soft layer using a REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for a REST API to register a domain name in Soft Layer, which I will be using for the machines or VMs I am provisioning.

Looks like the same can be done using this class
http://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/managers/dns/

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

To [Register New Domain](https://control.softlayer.com/services/domains) as Control Portal does,  you should try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Dns_Domain_Registration",
         "quantity":1,
         "packageId":0,
         "administrativeContact":{  
            "address1":"address test",
            "city":"cityTest",
            "country":"BO",
            "email":"noreply@softlayer.com",
            "firstName":"Jhon",
            "lastName":"Travolta",
            "organizationName":"Company Name",
            "phone":"7074485559",
            "postalCode":"0591",
            "state":"OT",
            "type":"admin"
         },
         "billingContact":{  
            "address1":"address test",
            "city":"cityTest",
            "country":"BO",
            "email":"noreply@softlayer.com",
            "firstName":"Jhon",
            "lastName":"Travolta",
            "organizationName":"Company Name",
            "phone":"7074485559",
            "postalCode":"0591",
            "state":"OT",
            "type":"billing"
         },
         "ownerContact":{  
            "address1":"address test",
            "city":"cityTest",
            "country":"BO",
            "email":"noreply@softlayer.com",
            "firstName":"Jhon",
            "lastName":"Travolta",
            "organizationName":"Company Name",
            "phone":"7074485559",
            "postalCode":"0591",
            "state":"OT",
            "type":"owner"
         },
         "technicalContact":{  
            "address1":"address test",
            "city":"cityTest",
            "country":"BO",
            "email":"noreply@softlayer.com",
            "firstName":"Jhon",
            "lastName":"Travolta",
            "organizationName":"Company Name",
            "phone":"7074485559",
            "postalCode":"0591",
            "state":"OT",
            "type":"tech"
         },
         "domainRegistrationList":[  
            {  
               "domainName":"testrcv.com",
               "registrationPeriod":1
            }
         ],
         "registrationType":"new"
      }
   ]
}
```

Anyway, if you wish to [Add DNS Zone](https://control.softlayer.com/network/dns/forwardzones), try the following:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "name":"test.com",
         "serial":374597345,
         "resourceRecords":{  

         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Also, if you wish to add a new record inside your DNS Zone, you should try the following:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "domainId":1609439,
         "ttl":900,
         "data":"127.0.0.1",
         "host": "@",
         "type":"a"
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope this information be helpful for you

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder)
- [SoftLayer_Dns_Domain::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createObject)
- [SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject)

Comment: Hi Ruber,  Thanks for the reply. I have tried the last API, and it gives the error "Permission denied to createObject.". Can you please throw light on what could be going wrong?

Comment: The exception is related to permissions, probably your account doesn't have this permission enabled: **Manage DNS, Reverse DNS and WHOIS**, ask or check it with your parent/master user.